# How to convert coordinates (x, y) in feet to pixels

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geometry, fabricjs

I have the real-time locations(x, y) of on object(antenna in my case) in **feet** and I want to display them on the fabricJs canvas (width : 400px and height: 400px) in **pixels**, however I don't know the formula for **converting feet measurements to pixels**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to scale the map down to a 400px by 400px grid. Assuming you have a l x w sized real-time map you could do something like:

```
function positionToPixels(x, y) { 
    //You may want to parseInt or something
    let newX = 400 * x / w;
    let newY = 400 * y / l;
    return [newX, newY];
}
```

All we're doing is saying the distance from the edges the original object is is going to be proportional to the distance the mapped object is from its edges

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the area in **feet**.
If area in feet = 1000x1000 you can do:

```
const areaF = {w: 1000, h: 1000};
const areaP = {w: 400, h: 400};
const locationFeetToPixel (x, y) {
    const relativeX = x / areaF.w;
    const relativeY = y / areaF.h;
    const pX = areaP.w * relativeX;
    const pY = areaP.h * relativeY;
    return {x: pX, y: pY};
}
```

Comment: What is relativeX and relativeY ? Are there the scaling measurements ?

Comment: Yes, the ratio relative to the total size. For example if x = 0 than relativeX = 0, if x = 1000 than relativeX = 1. All the values in between are in range 0 to 1.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just Concat your width and height values with string "px" and apply using CSS

Comment: You mean real width and height values of the area in feet ?

Comment: @Xris as we get that in number, hence simple to concat and use like css property with help of JS

Comment: how to do that in CSS, again css property values must be in pixels, and i have values in feet. Thanks for the feedback